# How do I change the radio button values in android?

Tags: java, android, radio-button

I am creating a quiz app for android with 10 question but every time I hit next button on the screen for the new question to display, the radio buttons for the new questions somehow have the information saved for the previous question. Even if I check the right radio button for the new question, it displays incorrect but says the answer is right if I select the third radio button. I tried different things but its still the same result. Please help.

```
public class MainActivity2 extends ActionBarActivity {
    private Questions[] questions = new Questions[10];
    private int qNum = 0;
    Button next;
    RadioButton op1, op2, op3, op4;
    ImageView imageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity2);

        imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.saturn);

        initQuestions();
        initNextButton();
        initQuestionText();
        answers();
    }

    private void initNextButton(){
        final RadioButton rb1 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.op1RBtn);
        final RadioButton rb2 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.op2RBtn);
        final RadioButton rb3 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.op3RBtn);
        final RadioButton rb4 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.op4RBtn);
        final TextView textView2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        final RadioGroup rg = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
        Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.nextBtn);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                qNum++;
                initQuestionText();
                initOptions();

                if(questions[qNum] == questions[1]){
                    textView2.setText("");
                    rg.clearCheck();
                    rb1.setChecked(false);
                    rb1.invalidate();
                    rb2.setChecked(false);
                    rb2.invalidate();
                    rb3.setChecked(false);
                    rb3.invalidate();
                    rb4.setChecked(false);
                    rb4.invalidate();
                }
                if(questions[qNum] == questions[1]){
                    textView2.setText("");
                    rg.clearCheck();
                    rb1.setChecked(false);
                    rb1.invalidate();
                    rb2.setChecked(false);
                    rb2.invalidate();
                    rb3.setChecked(false);
                    rb3.invalidate();
                    rb4.setChecked(false);
                    rb4.invalidate();
                }
                if(questions[qNum] == questions[2]){
                    textView2.setText("");
                    rg.clearCheck();
                    rb1.setChecked(false);
                    rb1.invalidate();
                    rb2.setChecked(false);
                    rb2.invalidate();
                    rb3.setChecked(false);
                    rb3.invalidate();
                    rb4.setChecked(false);
                    rb4.invalidate();
                }
                if(questions[qNum] == questions[3]){
                    textView2.setText("");
                    rg.clearCheck();
                    rb1.setChecked(false);
                    rb1.invalidate();
                    rb2.setChecked(false);
                    rb2.invalidate();
                    rb3.setChecked(false);
                    rb3.invalidate();
                    rb4.setChecked(false);
                    rb4.invalidate();
                }
                if(questions[qNum] == questions[4]){
                    textView2.setText("");
                    rg.clearCheck();
                    rb1.setChecked(false);
                    rb1.invalidate();
                    rb2.setChecked(false);
                    rb2.invalidate();
                    rb3.setChecked(false);
                    rb3.invalidate();
                    rb4.setChecked(false);
                    rb4.invalidate();
                }
                if(questions[qNum] == questions[5]){
                    textView2.setText("");
                    rg.clearCheck();
                    rb1.setChecked(false);
                    rb1.invalidate();
                    rb2.setChecked(false);
                    rb2.invalidate();
                    rb3.setChecked(false);
                    rb3.invalidate();
                    rb4.setChecked(false);
                    rb4.invalidate();
                }
                if(questions[qNum] == questions[6]){
                    textView2.setText("");
                    rg.clearCheck();
                    rb1.setChecked(false);
                    rb1.invalidate();
                    rb2.setChecked(false);
                    rb2.invalidate();
                    rb3.setChecked(false);
                    rb3.invalidate();
                    rb4.setChecked(false);
                    rb4.invalidate();
                }
                if(questions[qNum] == questions[7]){
                    textView2.setText("");
                    rg.clearCheck();
                    rb1.setChecked(false);
                    rb1.invalidate();
                    rb2.setChecked(false);
                    rb2.invalidate();
                    rb3.setChecked(false);
                    rb3.invalidate();
                    rb4.setChecked(false);
                    rb4.invalidate();
                }
                if(questions[qNum] == questions[8]){
                    textView2.setText("");
                    rg.clearCheck();
                    rb1.setChecked(false);
                    rb1.invalidate();
                    rb2.setChecked(false);
                    rb2.invalidate();
                    rb3.setChecked(false);
                    rb3.invalidate();
                    rb4.setChecked(false);
                    rb4.invalidate();
                }
                if(questions[qNum] == questions[9]){
                    textView2.setText("");
                    rg.clearCheck();
                    rb1.setChecked(false);
                    rb1.invalidate();
                    rb2.setChecked(false);
                    rb2.invalidate();
                    rb3.setChecked(false);
                    rb3.invalidate();
                    rb4.setChecked(false);
                    rb4.invalidate();
                    Button fin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.nextBtn);
                    fin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                        public void onClick(View v){
                            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity2.this, MainActivity3.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void initQuestionText(){
        TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        textView.setText(questions[qNum].getQuery());
    }

    private void initQuestions(){
        questions[0] = new Questions("What is the fifth planet in the solar system?");
        questions[1] = new Questions("What is the chemical symbol for Sodium?");
        questions[2] = new Questions("What is HCl?");
        questions[3] = new Questions("How many bones in a human body?");
        questions[4] = new Questions("How many teeth does an average human have?");
        questions[5] = new Questions("What came first? Chicken or the Egg?");
        questions[6] = new Questions("What is high in citric acid?");
        questions[7] = new Questions("What family does the whale belong to?");
        questions[8] = new Questions("What is water made of?");
        questions[9] = new Questions("What percentage of Nitrogen does the atmosphere contain?");
    }

    private void answers(){
        final RadioButton rb1 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.op1RBtn);
        final RadioButton rb2 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.op2RBtn);
        final RadioButton rb3 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.op3RBtn);
        final RadioButton rb4 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.op4RBtn);

        RadioGroup rg = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);

        final TextView textView2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);

        if(questions[qNum] == questions[0]){
            rb1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    textView2.setText("NOPE! SORRY! :(");
                }
            });
            rb2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    textView2.setText("NOPE! SORRY! :(");
                }
            });
            rb3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    textView2.setText("YAY! YOU GOT IT!");
                }
            });
            rb4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    textView2.setText("NOPE! SORRY! :(");
                }
            });
        }

        if(questions[qNum] == questions[1]){
            rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener(){

                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                    rb1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            textView2.setText("YAY! YOU GOT IT!");
                        }
                    });
                    rb2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            textView2.setText("NOPE! SORRY! :(");
                        }
                    });
                    rb3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            textView2.setText("NOPE! SORRY! :(");
                        }
                    });
                    rb4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            textView2.setText("NOPE! SORRY! :(");
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }

        if(questions[qNum] == questions[2]){
            rb1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    textView2.setText("NOPE! SORRY! :(");
                }
            });
            rb2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    textView2.setText("YAY! YOU GOT IT!");
                }
            });
            rb3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    textView2.setText("NOPE! SORRY! :(");
                }
            });
            rb4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    textView2.setText("NOPE! SORRY! :(");
                }
            });
        }

        if(questions[qNum] == questions[3]){
            rb1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    textView2.setText("NOPE! SORRY! :(");
                }
            });
            rb2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    textView2.setText("NOPE! SORRY! :(");
                }
            });
            rb3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    textView2.setText("NOPE! SORRY! :(");
                }
            });
            rb4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    textView2.setText("YAY! YOU GOT IT!");
                }
            });
        }

        if(questions[qNum] == questions[4]){
            rb1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    textView2.setText("NOPE! SORRY! :(");
                }
            });
            rb2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    textView2.setText("YAY! YOU GOT IT!");
                }
            });
            rb3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    textView2.setText("NOPE! SORRY! :(");
                }
            });
            rb4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    textView2.setText("NOPE! SORRY! :(");
                }
            });
        }

        if(questions[qNum] == questions[5]){
            rb1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    textView2.setText("NOPE! SORRY! :(");
                }
            });
            rb2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    textView2.setText("NOPE! SORRY! :(");
                }
            });
            rb3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    textView2.setText("YAY! YOU GOT IT!");
                }
            });
            rb4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    textView2.setText("NOPE! SORRY! :(");
                }
            });
        }

        if(questions[qNum] == questions[6]){
            rb1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    textView2.setText("NOPE! SORRY! :(");
                }
            });
            rb2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    textView2.setText("NOPE! SORRY! :(");
                }
            });
            rb3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    textView2.setText("NOPE! SORRY! :(");
                }
            });
            rb4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    textView2.setText("YAY! YOU GOT IT!");
                }
            });
        }

        if(questions[qNum] == questions[7]){
            rb1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    textView2.setText("NOPE! SORRY! :(");
                }
            });
            rb2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    textView2.setText("YAY! YOU GOT IT!");
                }
            });
            rb3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    textView2.setText("NOPE! SORRY! :(");
                }
            });
            rb4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    textView2.setText("NOPE! SORRY! :(");
                }
            });
        }

        if(questions[qNum] == questions[8]){
            rb1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    textView2.setText("NOPE! SORRY! :(");
                }
            });
            rb2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    textView2.setText("NOPE! SORRY! :(");
                }
            });
            rb3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    textView2.setText("YAY! YOU GOT IT!");
                }
            });
            rb4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    textView2.setText("NOPE! SORRY! :(");
                }
            });
        }

        if(questions[qNum] == questions[9]){
            rb1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    textView2.setText("YAY! YOU GOT IT!");
                }
            });
            rb2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    textView2.setText("NOPE! SORRY! :(");
                }
            });
            rb3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    textView2.setText("NOPE! SORRY! :(");
                }
            });
            rb4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    textView2.setText("NOPE! SORRY! :(");
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private void initOptions(){
        imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.saturn);
        if(questions[qNum] == questions[0]) {
            op1 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.op1RBtn);
            op1.setText("Neptune");
            op2 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.op2RBtn);
            op2.setText("Saturn");
            op3 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.op3RBtn);
            op3.setText("Jupiter");
            op4 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.op4RBtn);
            op4.setText("Earth");
        }
        else if(questions[qNum] == questions[1]) {
            op1 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.op1RBtn);
            op1.setText("Na");
            op2 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.op2RBtn);
            op2.setText("So");
            op3 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.op3RBtn);
            op3.setText("Di");
            op4 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.op4RBtn);
            op4.setText("Sa");

            imageView.setImageResource(android.R.color.transparent);
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.sodium);
        }
        else if(questions[qNum] == questions[2]) {
            op1 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.op1RBtn);
            op1.setText("Base");
            op2 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.op2RBtn);
            op2.setText("Acid");
            op3 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.op3RBtn);
            op3.setText("Solid");
            op4 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.op4RBtn);
            op4.setText("Liquid");

            imageView.setImageResource(android.R.color.transparent);
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.acid);
        }
        else if(questions[qNum] == questions[3]) {
            op1 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.op1RBtn);
            op1.setText("200");
            op2 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.op2RBtn);
            op2.setText("183");
            op3 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.op3RBtn);
            op3.setText("300");
            op4 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.op4RBtn);
            op4.setText("206");

            imageView.setImageResource(android.R.color.transparent);
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.skeleton);
        }
        else if(questions[qNum] == questions[4]) {
            op1 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.op1RBtn);
            op1.setText("20");
            op2 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.op2RBtn);
            op2.setText("32");
            op3 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.op3RBtn);
            op3.setText("34");
            op4 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.op4RBtn);
            op4.setText("38");

            imageView.setImageResource(android.R.color.transparent);
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.tooth);
        }
        else if(questions[qNum] == questions[5]) {
            op1 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.op1RBtn);
            op1.setText("Chicken");
            op2 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.op2RBtn);
            op2.setText("Egg");
            op3 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.op3RBtn);
            op3.setText("I Don't Know");
            op4 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.op4RBtn);
            op4.setText("The Hen Came First");

            imageView.setImageResource(android.R.color.transparent);
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.chicken);
        }
        else if(questions[qNum] == questions[6]) {
            op1 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.op1RBtn);
            op1.setText("Apple");
            op2 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.op2RBtn);
            op2.setText("Mango");
            op3 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.op3RBtn);
            op3.setText("Banana");
            op4 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.op4RBtn);
            op4.setText("Oranges");

            imageView.setImageResource(android.R.color.transparent);
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.fruits);
        }
        else if(questions[qNum] == questions[7]) {
            op1 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.op1RBtn);
            op1.setText("Reptile");
            op2 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.op2RBtn);
            op2.setText("Mammal");
            op3 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.op3RBtn);
            op3.setText("Amphibians");
            op4 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.op4RBtn);
            op4.setText("Cave Fish");

            imageView.setImageResource(android.R.color.transparent);
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.whale);
        }
        else if(questions[qNum] == questions[8]) {
            op1 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.op1RBtn);
            op1.setText("CO2 and O");
            op2 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.op2RBtn);
            op2.setText("H and O");
            op3 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.op3RBtn);
            op3.setText("H2 and O");
            op4 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.op4RBtn);
            op4.setText("CH4 and H");

            imageView.setImageResource(android.R.color.transparent);
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.water);
        }
        else {
            op1 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.op1RBtn);
            op1.setText("78%");
            op2 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.op2RBtn);
            op2.setText("55%");
            op3 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.op3RBtn);
            op3.setText("34%");
            op4 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.op4RBtn);
            op4.setText("88%");

            imageView.setImageResource(android.R.color.transparent);
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.air);

            next = (Button)findViewById(R.id.nextBtn);
            next.setText("");
            next.setText("Finish");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main_activity2, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show where `qNum` is being set? You have ten questions but only two configurations for answers. You're going to need to come up with a way to do that more concisely for 10 questions; lots of repetition there.

Comment: You'll need to show more than what you have, such as where you set the question and subsequently call `answers()`, since it seems you've got a lag in your call chain somewhere, which is leading you to see incorrect behavior.

Comment: Yes there is a lot of repetition :(

Comment: I have posted the full code

Answer (score 0):

Try in this manner, no need to use on click on radio buttons

```
RadioGroup group=(RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
 group.setOnCheckedChangeListener(
new OnCheckedChangeListener() { 
public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) { 
// TODO Auto-generated method stub 
if(radiobutton1.isChecked()) {
 // put your code here
} else if(radiobutton2.isChecked()) {
// put your code here
 }
 } 
});
```